# how to use the sum rule of derivatives when an additional function of x is present which is not a derivative

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, derivatives

I was reading a text book which includes the function

$$\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!} q^{N-n} \frac{\partial}{\partial p} p^n$$
all of the equation above is contained within the summation.

Then it says that by interchanging the order of summation and differentiation you get

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial p} \sum_{n= 0}^N \frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!} q^{N-n}p^n$$
all of the equation above is contained within the summation

I would understand if there was just the derivative inside the sum because that follows the rule that the sum of the derivatives are equal to the derivatives of the sum, but there is an additional function of $x$ in addition to the derivative

Using the sum rules for derivatives you run into a problem

(I represented the function above as the two functions below)

$$\sum_{n=0}^N f_n(x)g_n'(x)$$

According to the rules of differentiation that I know the $f_n(x)$'s needs to be factored out before you can take the derivative of the sum but the book doesn't show that it did that and I wouldn't know how to do that myself because each term that is added in the sequence would have n changed by one.

Please help I'm so confused

Comment: Do you accept that $q^m \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d p} p^n=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d p} q^ m p^n$ or does $q$ depend implicitly $p$ in a way you didn't mention?

Comment: The sum is finite so I dont see a problem to exchange summation symbol and (partial) derivative. Remember that $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}(f(x)+g(x))=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}f(x)+\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}g(x)$

Comment: If $q=1-p$ then $\frac{\mathrm d q^n}{\mathrm d p} = \frac{\mathrm d (1-p)^n}{\mathrm d p} = - n q^{n-1}$ and you're equation doesn't work. I'm assuming you might be doing something with probabilities where you would have $p=1-q$

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it -- please correct me if I'm wrong -- your problem is not with the idea of applying the sum rule to move differentiation from one side of a finite sum to the other but with the fact that you think that you need to differentiate the term in $q$ somehow. Certainly you might want to do this if $q$ depends on $p$. However if you are taking a partial derivative then you treat other variables as constants. I can't see the book you're looking at but it may be that $q$ did depend on $p$ but you have to assume it is independent for the purpose of, say, evaluating a sum.

Here is how it works if you assume that $q$ doesn't depend on $p.$

$$\sum_0^N f(n)g(q,n)\frac\partial{\partial p}h(p,n) = f(0)g(q,0)\frac\partial{\partial p}h(p,0) +\cdots + f(N)g(q,N)\frac\partial{\partial p}h(p,N) = \frac\partial{\partial p}f(0)g(q,0)h(p,0) +\cdots + \frac\partial{\partial p}f(N)g(q,N)h(p,N)
$$

The last step is ok as the other functions don't depend on $p$ and a partial derivative keeps everything else constant. We continue:
$$= \frac\partial{\partial p}\bigl(f(0)g(q,0)h(p,0)+\cdots+f(N)g(q,N)h(p,N)\bigr)$$
This step is by the linearity of differentiation (the sum rule).
$$=\frac\partial{\partial p}\sum_0^Nf(n)g(q,n)h(p,n)$$
Now we are done.

Comment: The problem I have is getting from the equation on the top to the second equation from the top. I don't care about everything besides d/dp just that its there and that you cant use the derivative sum rule because of that. Also every term is independent of each other.

Comment: Wait 1-q = p but i dont think that effects anything

Comment: Someone edited my post and changed my equation in a way that made it look like a summation multiplied by a partial derivative when it was just a summation with everything coming after sigma being contained inside it.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'm still not quite sure if I've figured out what your problem is